# AOS animations don't trigger until I zoom in/out

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, aos.js

As stated in the title, my AOS animations don't trigger whatsoever unless I zoom in or out, open console or resize the browser. The content ony my page still displays when the animations aren't triggered, but I'd obviously prefer if the animations worked correctly. I'll provide a snippet of my code below, if anyone can spot any errors or has prior experience with this issue please let me know how I can add a fix. Ty in advance.

```
 <div
          className="flex flex-col md:flex-row justify-center items-center mt-20"
          data-aos="fade-in"
          data-aos-duration="1200"
        >
          <div className="text-center md:text-left pb-4 px-8">
            <h2 className="text-2xl text-gray-600">Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <h2 className="text-base text-gray-700">
            Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum.
            </h2>
          </div>
          <img
            src={profiles}
            class="w-4/5 md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/3 mx-8 shadow-md hover:shadow-lg trans-3"
          />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, found a solution. For anyone in the future who has a similar problem, I added:

```
<script>
 window.addEventListener("load", Aos.refresh);
</script>
```

to the top of my HTML file and that seemed to solve the problem.